# OPenMS TOPPAS can't find Java

Tags: java, osx-elcapitan

OSX 10.11.5
TOPPAS v2.0.0(66a7739)

I'm new to OpenMS and TOPPAS. I'm attempting to implement the DeMIX TOPPAS workflow found here:
https://github.com/userbz/DeMix

I believe I have everything configured correctly. I've altered the .toppas file according to the readme, including changing all the paths.

The workflow uses "MSGFPlus.jar", which is showing as the correct path in the workflow (.toppas). However, when I run the workflow, I get the error…

> Fatal error: Java not found. Java is needed to run MS-GF+. Make sure that it can be executed by calling 'java', e.g. add the directory containing the Java binary to your PATH variable."

I believe TOPP is running as my local user, however it doesn't seem to matter if I run as the local user or root. The error suggests I check that java is in my path, which it appears to be for both the local user and root.

> Mikes-MacBook-Pro:~ mikes$ java -version 
>   java version "1.8.0_74"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)
>   Mikes-MacBook-Pro:~ mikes$
>   Mikes-MacBook-Pro:~ mikes$ sudo bash
>   Password:
>   bash-3.2# java -version 
>   java version "1.8.0_74"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)
>   bash-3.2#

EDIT:
I have tried opening TOPPAS.app from the command line using 'open', and adding '/usr/bin/java' to the Info.plist...as suggested [here](http://ftp.mi.fu-berlin.de/pub/OpenMS/release-documentation/html/install_mac_bin.html), but I still get the same error.

EDIT:
The .jar file in question does run OK at the command line...

```
Mikes-MacBook-Pro:MSGFPlus mikes$ java -jar ./MSGFPlus.jar -s /Users/.../DeMix-master/Example/20131106_Q2_SDC_120MIN_HELA1.mzML -d /Users/.../2016-21-07_uniprot_sprot.fasta 
MS-GF+ Beta (v10089) (7/16/2014)
Loading database files...
Creating the suffix array indexed file... Size: 197666693
AlphabetSize: 28
Suffix creation: 0.00% complete.
Suffix creation: 5.06% complete.
(snip)
Sorting 0.00% complete.
Sorting 5.81% complete.
(snip)
Sorting 98.78% complete.
Loading database finished (elapsed time: 207.38 sec)
Reading spectra...
Ignoring spectrum controllerType=0 controllerNumber=1 scan=20845: spectrum is not centroided.
(snip)
Ignoring spectrum controllerType=0 controllerNumber=1 scan=21339: spectrum is not centroided.
Ignoring 421 profile spectra.
Ignoring 0 spectra having less than 10 peaks.
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer came from the TOPPAS mailing list.

This is a bug, and they're adding a fix to the next release.

The work around is to start the TOPPAS from a command prompt, using the TOPPAS file WITHIN the app contents.

I.E.
$/Applications/OpenMS-2.0.0/TOPPAS.app/Contents/MacOS/TOPPAS